# How to return a non empty data frame among multiple newly created data frames inside a function in python?

Tags: python, list, function, dataframe

I am new to pandas, I have a doubt in returning a data frame from a function. I have a function which creates three new data frames based on the parameters given to it, the function has to return only the data frames which are non-empty. How do I do that?

```
my code:
 def df_r(df,colname,t1):
    t1_df = pd.DataFrame()
    t2_df = pd.DataFrame()
    t3_df = pd.DataFrame()
    if t1 :
      for colname in df:
           some code
           some code
           t1_df = some data
    if t2 :
      for colname in df:
           some code
           some code
           t2_df = some data
    if t3 :
      for colname in df:
           some code
           some code
           t3_df = some data
    list = [t1_df,t2_df,t3_df]
```

Now it should return only the t1_df as the parameter was given t1. So I have inserted all three into a list

```
list = [t1_df,t2_df,t3_df]
```

how to check if which df is non-empty and return it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for `empty` attribute for each `DataFrame`

eg.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
if df.empty:
    print("DataFrame is empty")
```

output:

```
DataFrame is empty
```

pd.empty would return `True` if DataFrame is empty, else it would return `False`

This would work even if column names are present but are still missing the data.

So to answer specific to your case

```
list = [t1_df,t2_df,t3_df]
for df in list:
    if not df.empty:
        return df
```

assuming your case has only one of the DataFrame non-empty

Comment: I would like to return if the df is non-empty

Answer (score 0):

```
if t1_df.empty != True:
        return t1_df
    elif t2_df.empty !=True:
        return t2_df
    else:
        return t2_df
```